# how to make it print empty

Tags: javascript, if-statement

was wondering how I can get this to print out empty.
I tried change the humans value to 0 but it still prints 'lesser people'

```
let human = 0;

if (human > 10) {
  console.log('Too many people');
} else if (human <= 10) {
  console.log('lesser people');
} else {
  console.log('empty');
}
```

Comment: As it stands any value will be caught by the first 2 if statements unless human is null or undefined.

Comment: else if (human == 0) { ... } else if (human <= 10) { .... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tried value as

```
let human = 0;
```

Which is less than `10` that's why it prints `lesser people`

---

If you want to print `empty`

Just define as

```
const human = undefined
// or
let human;
```

```js
const human = undefined;

if (human > 10) {
  console.log("Too many people");
} else if (human <= 10) {
  console.log("lesser people");
} else {
  console.log("empty");
}
```

Comment: OP asked *how I can get this to print out empty*

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong that was OP primary concern that `how I can get this to print out empty`. BTW I've edited my answer for that one too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The current logic is checking for two conditions:

1. If `human` is greater than 10
2. If `human` is less than or equal to 10

It appears, however, that you are looking to check for a third possibility - if `human` equals 0. To check for this, you will need to add an additional `if` clause. Try the following:

```js
let human = 0;

if (!human || human === 0) {
  console.log('empty');
} else if (human > 10) {
  console.log('Too many people');
} else if (human <= 10) {
  console.log('lesser people');
}
```

This additional clause also checks for `human` being falsey.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, before going to else case your code checks the following

```
else if (human <= 10) {
  console.log('lesser people');
```

So, 0 is also a value <=10, so you get as "lesser people" and since that 'else if' is satisfied, the program is not going into else case.
If you need to print "empty" for zero change your condition as something like below

```
    let human = 0;

if (human > 10) {
  console.log('Too many people');
} else if (human >0) {
  console.log('lesser people');
} else {
  console.log('empty');
}
```

in the above code, if human >10 it prints "Too many people" and not consider the other cases. if not >10 then checks the human>0 condition and if it's true prints 'lesser people'. if both above conditions are not satisfied, the program considers the else case. Ex : when human=0 you'll get 'empty' as printed value

Answer (score 0):

The `elseif` will work only if both the operations are true because of the use of `&&` the exclamation mark `!` defines that if it is not equal to zero and less than ten run it if it is 0 then it will print 'empty'

```js
let human = 0;

if (human > 10) {
  console.log('Too many people');
} else if (human <= 10 && human != 0) {
  console.log('lesser people');
} else {
  console.log('empty');
}
```